# Cosine similarity calculation in Rust, which is slower than NumPy

Tags: performance, algorithm, rust, matrix

I'm running this in release mode. Currently, the following function takes around 6.7 seconds to run on my computer vs 3.7 seconds on Python. I know that Numpy is just calling to C, but I'm trying to reach faster performance on the Rust version. I would appreciate any help. I've been trying for a week to do this, with no success.

Here is the code.

```rust
#[inline]
fn l2_norm<MatrixType>(x: ArrayView1<MatrixType>) -> MatrixType
where
    MatrixType: LinalgScalar + num::Float,
{
    x.dot(&x).sqrt()
}

#[inline]
fn cosine_similarity_helper<MatrixType>(
    vector_one: ArrayView1<MatrixType>,
    vector_two: ArrayView1<MatrixType>,
) -> MatrixType
where
    MatrixType: LinalgScalar + Float,
{
    let dot_product = vector_one.dot(&vector_two);
    let vector_one_norm = l2_norm(vector_one);
    let vector_two_norm = l2_norm(vector_two);

    dot_product / (vector_one_norm * vector_two_norm)
}

fn cosine_similarity<MatrixType>(
    x_embed: ArrayView2<MatrixType>,
    y_embed: ArrayView2<MatrixType>,
) -> Result<Array2<MatrixType>, AlgorithmError>
where
    MatrixType: LinalgScalar + Float,
{
    if x_embed.ncols() != y_embed.ncols() {
        return Err(AlgorithmError::DimensionMismatch(
            "x and y must have the same number of columns".to_string(),
        ));
    }

    // the shape of the score matrix will be (n_samples_x by n_samples_y)
    let (rows, cols) = (x_embed.nrows(), y_embed.nrows());
    let mut elements = Vec::with_capacity(rows * cols);
    for i in 0..rows {
        for j in 0..cols {
            elements.push(cosine_similarity_helper(x_embed.row(i), y_embed.row(j)));
        }
    }
    Ok(Array2::from_shape_vec((rows, cols), elements)?)
}
```

and here are some test cases.

```rust
    #[test]
    fn test_cosine_similarity() {
    // assumes that there are 128 elements per line
        pub const ELEMENTS_PER_LINE: usize = 128;

        // read human embedds from a file
        let human_embedds = fs::read_to_string(
            "./rust_ndarry/human_embedds.txt",
        )
        .expect("Something went wrong reading the file");

        // let length = human_embedds.lines().count();
        // let mut elements: Vec<f64> = Vec::with(length * 128);
        let mut length = 0;
        let mut elements = Vec::new();
        human_embedds.lines().for_each(|line| {
            length += 1;
            elements.extend(line.split(' ').filter_map(|x| x.parse::<f64>().ok()));
        });

        let human_embedds = Array2::from_shape_vec((length, ELEMENTS_PER_LINE), elements)
            .expect("Failed to create matrix");

        // read mouse embedds from a file
        let mouse_embedds = fs::read_to_string(
            "./rust_ndarry/mouse_embedds.txt",
        )
        .expect("Something went wrong reading the file");

        let mut length = 0;
        let mut elements = Vec::new();
        mouse_embedds.lines().for_each(|line| {
            length += 1;
            elements.extend(line.split(' ').filter_map(|x| x.parse::<f64>().ok()));
        });

        let mouse_embedds = Array2::from_shape_vec((length, ELEMENTS_PER_LINE), elements)
            .expect("Failed to create matrix");

        // cosine_similarity
        let score_matrix = cosine_similarity(human_embedds.view(), mouse_embedds.view())
            .expect("it works in python lol");
        //
        // println!("{}", score_matrix[[0, 0]]);

        // println!("{:?}", human_embedds.shape());
        // println!("{:?}", mouse_embedds.shape());
    }
```

Here is the Python code that is equivalent:

```py
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import numpy as np

human_embeds = np.loadtxt("human_embeds") 
mouse_embeds = np.loadtxt("mouse_embeds") 
score_matrix = cosine_similarity(human_embeds,mouse_embeds)
```

Comment: did you check what the numpy c library is actually doing, and compare it to your Rust implementation?

Comment: You wrote the Python code, right? So I'm de-quoting it.

Comment: hello @Esther, I'm glad to say that instead of being 2x, my new implementation is around 2x faster! I'll edit the code with the solution!

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 5 → 4. If you have an improvement to share, please post it as a self-answer instead (and also include a bit of explanation to provide insight into how you achieved the performance gain).

Answer (score 1):

So @200_success undid the edit by the original asker (@Karl Hernandez) who hasn't logged for over a year (as of 2024-02-08). I'm posting @Karl Hernandez's answer here (since it works for me) so that future travelers can easily find it without having to read the comments and go through the edit history. I'll happily remove this answer if OP returns and posts their own.

---

Original answer with some small modifications for readability:

```rs
//! cargo add ndarray num_traits
fn normalize<MatrixType>(matrix: ndarray::ArrayView2<MatrixType>) -> Array2<MatrixType>
where
    MatrixType: ndarray::LinalgScalar + Default + num_traits::float::Float,
{
    let norms = matrix
        // square each element and add them up
        .map_axis(Axis(1), |row| {
            {
                row.iter()
                    .fold(MatrixType::default(), |acc, x| acc + x.powi(2))
            }
            // then take the square root of each sum
            .sqrt()
        })
        // we have created a new vector that is just one dimension
        // so to divide the elements like we want
        // we add a new axis to the matrix
        .insert_axis(Axis(1));
    &matrix / norms
}

fn cosine_similarity<MatrixType>(
    x_embed: ndarray::ArrayView2<MatrixType>,
    y_embed: ndarray::ArrayView2<MatrixType>,
) -> std::result::Result<ndarray::Array2<MatrixType>, String>
where
    MatrixType: ndarray::LinalgScalar + Default + num_traits::float::Float,
{
    if x_embed.ncols() != y_embed.ncols() {
        return Err("x and y must have the same number of columns".to_string());
    }

    // we need to normalize the embeddings
    // to get a faster cosine similarity
    // NOTE: that for y_embed we use the transpose
    // then we apply matrix multiplication
    Ok(normalize(x_embed).dot(&normalize(y_embed).t()))
}



#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use ndarray::{arr2, Array2, ArrayView2};

    #[test]
    fn test_cosine_similarity() {
        // Test case 1: Valid input
        let x_embed = arr2(&[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]]);
        let y_embed = arr2(&[[7.0, 8.0, 9.0], [10.0, 11.0, 12.0]]);
        let result = cosine_similarity(x_embed.view(), y_embed.view()).unwrap();
        let expected_result = arr2(&[
            [0.9594119455666703, 0.9512583076673059],
            [0.9981908926857269, 0.9961498555841327],
        ]);
        assert_eq!(result, expected_result);
    }
}
```

I've also added a test case at the end to check that the code works.

Comment: You should probably make this a Community Wiki answer, since it's not your own work.  It really ought to contain the insightful observation(s) as well as the modified code, but that might be harder for you as a third party.

Comment: I'm happy to do that, although I can't see how to make it a community wiki answer. I've only got 111 reputation, maybe I need more?

Comment: You only need [10 points reputation](/help/privileges/community-wiki); should see a check-box under the input area when you [edit].